# How to add API key into gmail

Tags: gmail

I have created a workflow so i can have chatgpt answer my customer service email but im not sure on how i can integrate it into gmail using an api key or java script code. On my website im able to go into the html code and paste it in to be integrated with it. However, im not sure how i can do this on gmail.

Im not sure what i should do because i can create an api key but cant find a place to paste an api from another aplication. I have gone into google and tried to add an api key but only seem to be able to create a new api of get one from the library.

Comment: I really liked this idea so [Can an AI help me handle support emails for my Freelance business?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0sgSCe9JOVg)

Answer (score 0):

Api keys are used to access public data.  Gmail data things like sending emails is private user data you need the permission of the owner of that data to access it.

You can use Oauth2 to authorize your application and then it will be able to send emails.   I recomend using a server sided version of JavaScript so that you can store your refresh token for later use.  [node.js quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs)